# Firebase messages on Python return success, but Android app don't receive messgae

Tags: python, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM API in Python app to send message to Android app. Everything seems to be working fine, and sending a message returns a success, But dose not call onMessageReceived() that needs to receive the message.

```
{'multicast_ids': [4032469777984266672], 'success': 1, 'failure': 0, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'results': [{'message_id': '0:1647775893746697%207ea77df9fd7ecd'}], 'topic_message_id': None}
```

onMessageReceived() in the Andriod app is never called, and I don't know why... Everything seems fine...

**What could be the problem?**

- it is a Python code problem or an Android code problem? Or is there
  problem with the computer setting?

My Python Code:

```python
import time
from pyfcm import FCMNotification

push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="AAAArIgWtH8:APA91bHIwFuE9-OGq3c8xWGUBL2hbsCd2ZEIn9fIWv9m_rBOZ1wiP1rjbNdTT12jaBQ8miqYxWpSoNVF_v4D4kdgeJFDRYvaYav6PmoOqbCVy1bqfx8sNCMEaL6n0g0lUwjNdXiqOZv9")

mToken = "dCKDAQ4xSmyT-eGe1B348L:APA91bElsno4aLHrqIRysHqWUVsNvkq86KQiQNeUG9W6O9WCKcX38gmDyxHIF6XB4CC0G4XNwKdciRQV_KxCl-hsaP1GOOT9_38FPlkXj6irwOMF1HnJNYk3bbfMvulD9Qz_pOXTvQHC"
nth = 0

def sendMessage(p):

    global nth
    nth += 1
    registration_id = mToken

    data_message = {
        "body" : str(nth) + " : test M"
    }
    
    result = push_service.single_device_data_message(registration_id=registration_id, data_message=data_message)
    print(result)

def _main():
    
    while True:
        sendMessage(80)
        time.sleep(60 * 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Answer (score 0):

To put simply, if your python code is correctly triggering the FCM API then you ought to get the message(s) at places where you have configured to listen to which is not the scenario in your case.

So imo one possible check you can do is the Firebase `SDK` setup in your Android App. If it is not done correctly, even if your backend code is able to invoke the FCM API, the FCM server will deploy the message(s)/notification(s) but your app will not just catch it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, notifications sent directly from Firebase can be found on the Android app. Isn't the firebase configuration good enough for Android apps?